# How can I not read the last line in a file?

Tags: r

Here is a simple file named test

```
Symbol|Security Name|Market Category|Test Issue|Financial Status|Round Lot Size
AAC|Australia Acquisition Corp. - Ordinary Shares|S|N|D|100
AACC|Asset Acceptance Capital Corp. - Common Stock|Q|N|N|100
AACOU|Australia Acquisition Corp. - Unit|S|N|N|100
File Creation Time: 0803201218:04|||||
```

If I don't need the last line in the file, I can do this:

```
data = read.table('test',sep='|')
data = data[1:(nrow(data)-1),1:ncol(data)]
```

Is there another way to do this directly when reading the file in?

Comment: I think it's fine, but just `data = data[1:(nrow(data)-1),]` is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat more compact would be:

```
data=data[ -nrow(data), ]
```

You might want to change your input command to read:

```
data = read.table('test', header = TRUE, sep = '|')
```

... since the default value for header is FALSE.

Comment: Or use `data = read.csv('test', sep='|')` as it has `header=TRUE` by default.

Comment: or even `head(data,-1)` -- although I find that pretty obscure.

Answer (score 6):

`?read.table` shows:

```
nrows   
integer: the maximum number of rows to read in. Negative and other invalid values are ignored.
```

So if you know the number of rows before reading it in, you could use that.

Comment: I usually count the number of rows with readLines() which helps me specify various arguments to read.table.